# Select another child of parent

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='card'>
    <div class='cardInfo'>
        <div class='line01 garn'></div>
        <div class='cardInfoB'>
            <div class='name'>323</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img class='cardBtn' src='btns/03.png' alt='img'>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".cardBtn").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).parent().find(".name").html();
    alert: (a);  // Null
});
```

The result is `Null` but I expect `323`.

Comment: This is working. http://jsfiddle.net/f9L8yyeg/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have corrected your code. Please have a look at jQuery code given  below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".cardBtn").click(function(){
    var a = $(this).parent().find(".name").text();
    alert(a);  
});
});
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/ekjb8n6o/

Note - If you want to show the text only then use text() property not html().

An example of this -

```
<div class='name'><div>323</div></div>
```

`alert($(this).parent().find(".name").html())` will alert `<div>323</div>`

But if you use `alert($(this).parent().find(".name").text())`  then it will alert 323.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the proper syntax,

`alert: (a);` is a wrong form of syntax, use just `alert(a);`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ns7g2z9t/)

Comment: `alert:` isn't a *"wrong form of syntax"*, nor will it throw any errors. In this case `alert:` is a [JavaScript label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) which contains the value `(a)`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yeah, just now noticed that. Thanks for pointing that. Actually OP's code completely changing the meaning of what he trying to do..